# Discrete Math multiplication principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many positive divisors of number 2646000 there?
To solve it by multiplication principle.
Should i test to divide it by something?

Comment: _Hint_: $2646000=10^3\cdot2646=10^3\cdot3\cdot882=10^3\cdot2\cdot3\cdot21^2=2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5^3\cdot7^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2646000=2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5^3\cdot7^2$, hence in every divisor:

- The factor $2$ can appear between $0$ and $4$ times, i.e., $5$ different ways
- The factor $3$ can appear between $0$ and $3$ times, i.e., $4$ different ways
- The factor $5$ can appear between $0$ and $3$ times, i.e., $4$ different ways
- The factor $7$ can appear between $0$ and $2$ times, i.e., $3$ different ways

Hence $2646000$ has $5\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3=240$ different divisors.

Comment: How do you mean by appear is it how many times you can divide it??

Comment: @JonasBo: The correct terminology is *Multiplicity*. For example, in $2^3\cdot5^1=40$, the multiplicity of $2$ is $3$ and the multiplicity of $5$ is $1$.